# How to make the boxes in a checkboxlist unchecked by default?

Tags: asp.net

I've tried looking at the properties for the asp.net checkboxlist on msdn and searching google and I can't seem to find a way of setting the checkboxes to unchecked as default. Am I missing a glaringly obvious solution?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default a `ListItem` in the `CheckBoxList` should not be checked. If you have the `Selected` property set to `true` then it would be checked:

```
<asp:ListItem Selected="True">Item 1</asp:ListItem>
```

By default it is false and this should suffice. If you need to clear all the checked items on demand you can use the [ClearSelection method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.clearselection.aspx): `checkboxlist.ClearSelection()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a set of *optional* check boxes, just use individual check boxes rather than a check box list.

Answer (score 1):

Won't this work?

All but "Check 2" will be unchecked.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="False">check 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">check 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="False">check 3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="False">check 4</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```